# Showing EntityRef column as result

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am new to LINQ to SQL and I am getting a weird result with my testing program that I don't want. 
The program is a very simple WinForms app that shows SQL results in a DataGridView.

Here is my database setup. 
[image: Image of Table relationships]

Here is the specific column information per table.

[image: Customer column info]

[image: Orders column info]

And finally here are the results of the table shown through MSMS

[image: Microsoft Server Management Studio select * results]

Here is the issue that i'm having.
After establishing the connection to the database, I then run the following.

```
testingDatabase = new DataClasses1DataContext(SharedVariables.TestingConnection);
        var query = from Orders in testingDatabase.GetTable<ORDER>()
                    select Orders;
                    //select new { Orders.CUST_ID, Orders.ORDER_NUM, Orders.ORDER_DATE };
        return query;
```

It returns this. 
[image: Results shown from select * statement]

I have also tried this code

```
testingDatabase = new DataClasses1DataContext(SharedVariables.TestingConnection);
        var query = from Orders in testingDatabase.ORDERs
                    select Orders;
                    //select new { Orders.CUST_ID, Orders.ORDER_NUM, Orders.ORDER_DATE };
        return query;
```

However the results are the same.

Then only way I can get the results i'm looking for is by doing this

```
testingDatabase = new DataClasses1DataContext(SharedVariables.TestingConnection);
        var query = from Orders in testingDatabase.GetTable<ORDER>()
                    //select Orders;
                    select new { Orders.CUST_ID, Orders.ORDER_NUM, Orders.ORDER_DATE };
        return query;
```

Then I finally get this. 
[image: Results after specifying select column]

Can anyone tell me how to do a "select customers" and have it not show the column displaying "LINQ_Testing.CUSTOMER". I suspect it's because it's the foreign key causing that since it makes an EntityRef variable in the CUSTOMER class.

Comment: Sorry it's not clear what do you mean by "select customers and have it now show that last column"

Comment: it's a typo. I was meaning to say "Can anyone tell me how to do a 'select customers' and have it not show the column LINQ_Testing.CUSTOMER

Comment: if you removed the relation in the diagram it will not show that column or if you need the relation you could hide it from grid or bind the grid to custom or anonymous object as you did

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a virtual object of Customer class in Order class:

```
public virtual Customer customer { get; set; }
```

The foreign key relation in Order class (i.e cust_id) will lazy load the Customer object in it automatically.